# Task model with EndUser model

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a task with the current user(EndUser), its title and date_created, but I can create the task with only `fields=['title']` specification. I'd like to have the user field automatically filled with an `EndUser`(current user) and a creation date.

models.py

```
class EndUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Tag(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (('My Day', 'My Day'),   
            ('Important', 'Important'),
            ('Planned', 'Planned'),)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(EndUser, null= True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    date_created= DateField(auto_now = True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
@authenticated_user
def mainPage(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'tasks': tasks[::-1], 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'tasks/todoList.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Add a task' , 'size': '5'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields =  ['title']
        #fields = "__all__"

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']
```

Tried the code below but this gives error `ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: user1212>>": "Task.user" must be a "EndUser" instance.`:

```
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            task =  form.save(commit=False)
            task.user = request.user # gives error
            task.save()
            return redirect('/')
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `request.user`, is likely a `user` object, not an `enduser` object. You can obtain the corresponding `EndUser` object with `request.user.enduser`, given of course the logged in user *has* a related `EndUser`:

```
@authenticated_user
def mainPage(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user.enduser
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'tasks': tasks[::-1], 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'tasks/todoList.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).